# AWK: consolidate table, write empty fields

Tags: awk

I have the following three files

```
file1:
1000001
1000002
100001  COG4658
100002  COG4656
100003
100004  COG2878
100005
100006  COG4657
100007

file2:
1000001
1000002 COG1943
100001  COG4658
100002  COG4656
100003
100004  COG2878
100005
100006  COG4657
100007

file3:
1000001
1000002 NOG04887
100001  COG4658
100002  COG4656
100003
100004  COG2878
100005
100006  COG4657
100007  COG2202
```

Now I wrote code that consolidates the files, and takes the values per id in the first column in the order file1 - file2 - file3 if a value should be missing.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NF > 1 {a[$1] = $2} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file3 file2 file1
```

This is giving me following output:

```
1000002 COG1943
100001  COG4658
100002  COG4656
100004  COG2878
100006  COG4657
100007  COG2202
```

Which is correct, but I would like to have all values of column 1 listed, also if the values are empty in all of the three files. How do I need to modify my code?

Comment: Please do mention expected output in code tags too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  count++
}
count==1{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
count==2{
  if(($1 in a) && a[$1]==""){
     a[$1]=$2
  }
  if(!($1 in a)){
     a[$1]=$2
  }
  next
}
count==3{
  print $1,a[$1]?a[$1]:$2
}
' OFS="\t"  Input_file1  Input_file2  Input_file3
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1000001
1000002 COG1943
100001  COG4658
100002  COG4656
100003
100004  COG2878
100005
100006  COG4657
100007  COG2202
```

Comment: the order of the files in `stdin` needs to be reversed, I tried it with a bigger dataset. Besides, works wonderfully! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the same key values in every file:

```
awk '
    { val[$1] = (val[$1]=="" ? $2 : val[$1]) }
    ARGIND==3 { print $1, val[$1] }
' file1 file2 file3
1000001
1000002 COG1943
100001 COG4658
100002 COG4656
100003
100004 COG2878
100005
100006 COG4657
100007 COG2202
```

The above uses GNU awk for ARGIND, with other awks use `FILENAME==ARGV[3]` instead of `ARGIND==3`.